# touch sensitivity of touch pad

Tags: touchpad

Since I upgraded my OS to Ubuntu Studio 20.04 (on an ASUS R753U laptop) I have to press harder on the touchpad. It was far more touch sensitive before and I liked that better. It doesn´t seem to be adjustable in settings or preferences and I couldn´t find any tutorials on YouTube. They only explain what to do, if the touchpad doesn´t work. But it does work. I only want my touch sensitivity back. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance
Ralf